# Webpack multiple entry point confusion

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

From my initial understanding of webpack's multiple entry point such as

```
entry: {
    a: "./a",
    b: "./b",
    c: ["./c", "./d"]
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].entry.js"
}
```

It will bundle them as a.entry.js, b.entry.js and c.entry.js. There is no d.entry.js since it's part of c.

However at work, these values are confusing me so much. Why is the value an http link and not a file?

```
app: [
  'webpack/hot/dev-server',
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:21200',
  './lib/index.js'
],
test: [
  'webpack/hot/dev-server',
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:21200',
  './test/test.js'
]
```

Comment: The http links you mean refer to the webpack-dev-server (a development server for serving your bundles). Those links are used to include the hotloading scripts into your bundle. They should be used in development only. For production, you would omit them, since you do not want the hotloading scripts to be in your prod files.

Comment: I'm interested to see a webpack.config.js for production. Thank you for sharing that tip. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated in a comment on the question, the HTTP URLs are used for webpack-dev-server and its hotloading module. However, you want to ommit those modules for the production version of your bundle, since you don't need the hotloading and it makes your bundle easily over 10.000 lines of code (additionally!).

For the personal interest of the poster, here is an example production config (minimalistic), for a project of mine (called dragJs).

```
// file: webpack.production.babel.js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve('./');

export default {
    entry: [
        path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, "src/drag")
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".scss"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, "build"),
        filename: "drag.min.js"
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                include: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'src')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

**A few things:**

- I only use one entry point, but you could use multiple, just as you do in your example
- The entry point only refers to my js file - no webpack-dev-server for production
- The config file is written using ECMAScript2015 (thus the name `*.babel.js`)
- It uses sourcemaps and an uglify optimization plugin
- The presets for the babel-loader are specified in my `.babelrc` file
- Run webpack with this config via `webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.babel.js`

If there are any further questions, I would be grateful to answer them in the comments.